# Infinite-dimensional Lie group corresponding to $U\mathfrak{g}$?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, infinite-dimensional-manifolds

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra. The universal enveloping algebra $U\mathfrak{g}$ is then an infinite-dimensional associative algebra which can be endowed with the structure of a Lie algebra. Is there an infinite-dimensional Lie group whose Lie algebra is $U\mathfrak{g}$? If so, what does this group look like?

Comment: Could you specify what you call an "infinite-dimensional Lie group"? The usual definition starts from a Banach manifold, so that the Lie algebra is a *complete* normable algebra — which $U(\mathfrak{g}$ is not.

Comment: The enveloping algebra gives you the invariant differential operators on the Lie group.